# Execute code after method has finished

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to execute some code after I know the keyboard is hidden.

Ive been looking in to blocks but I'm just not understanding how they work enough to do this...

All I want to do is run [self hidekeyboard] then when that is complete (and the keyboard fully hidden) then I want to call a delegate.

What is the best way to handle this and how?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the UIKeyboardDidHide notification and run your code in there. Here is the link in the docs...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html

Answer (score 2):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardDidHide:) name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And the `onKeyboardDidHide`:

```
-(void)onKeyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     // execute what you want.
}
```

Comment: You may also want to call `removeObserver` probably in `willDidDisAppear:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Register a listener for the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` using the `NSNotificationCenter` class.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardHidden:)
           name:UIKeyboardDidHideNorification
         object:nil];

- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *)notif
{
     // do stuff
}
```

(Don't forget to remove the observer in `- dealloc` so that no messages will erroneously be sent to deallocated objects.)

Comment: You may also want to call removeObserver probably in willDidDisAppear: method.

Comment: @Akash Rather in `-dealloc`.

Comment: In most cases this would be the solution but I cant use these methods for this because they are used for other conditions.  Adding in the delegate calls to these methods would break things in other places, and start to get kind of messy.  I'd have to start to get kind of hackey with my selectors and I dont want to go down that road

Comment: @JMD I don't understand your problem. If a selector is in use, use another.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to register to receive notifications of UIKeyboardDidHideNotification.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html